# MVC Passing Object on Re-Direction

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am missing something very obvious here.  I have two different solutions where the same code is behaving differently.  Essentially I am trying to recreate the code I have in one application into a rewrite of the same application.

It could be anyone of a dozen things so just looking for some ideas.

Essentially in both applications when I call the AddToCart method on the post, I get a populated cart and then redirect to the Index method.  In one application the cart is still populated when i get to the Index method in the new application the cart passed in is null.

Code

```
public ViewResult Index(Cart cart, string returnUrl)
{
    return View(new CartIndexViewModel
    {
        ReturnUrl = returnUrl,
        Cart = cart
    });
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddToCart(Cart cart, ShoppingCartProductItem product, string returnUrl)
{
    if (product != null)
    {
        cart.AddItem(product);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course it will be passed `null` because you are not passing `cart` to Index action while Redirecting on it:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", new { cart=cart, returnUrl= returnUrl });
```

or:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", new { cart,returnUrl });
```

Comment: Thanks - that doesn't really explain why it is working in the other application - its a direct copy and paste of code.  I did try what you suggested but it causes other problems down the path.  I have partially resolved it by changing a variable elsewhere in the code to static. Not good practice, I can also fix it with TempData.   So I am going to persevere as I want to try and understand what is going on.  Thank you for your advice

Comment: @ccocker there must be some difference in both application otherwise it will never be passed to `Index()` if you don't pass it explicitly

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, If `cart` is a complex object, it would need to be serialized (or passed using TempData)

Comment: you can pass it using `TempData` and need to cast it to its Type when accessing from `TempData`